# Basic filter that can be expanded to include additional filtering criteria

Tags: views

I have several filter criteria for examining different classes based on location,meeting time, etc. All the different filter options take up a lot of space and can look overwhelming to a new visitor. Is there a way to just have a few filter criteria initially visible with an option for the visitor to expand the filter criteria?